# Is it possible not to use voice commands?

Tags: google-glass

I don't like any of the listed commands in google glass and review team didn't approve my own. I want my glassware to by on official store so my question is:

Can I NOT use voice activation for an app and just start it using touchpad?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, and therefore is off-topic. You might be able to get help at [android.se] or [su] instead. The [help] has more information regarding the types of questions that are appropriate to ask here.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely it is possible to open an app without voice commands.

Instead of saying "Hello Glass" when the screen turns on, just tap on the touch pad, and it'll bring up a list of applications in chronological order of usage. You can scroll through them until you find the name of yours, and then tap to open it.

Comment: My friend I am asking if I can NOT use voice commands because I don't want MY app named after voice command that is not suitable for me. So what I want to achievie is - name my app whatever I want  so it displayed in menu as I say it is and I also want to disable voice command on it since it will be unlisted.

Comment: @zarcel.. Are you able to create a Glassware app with out using any voice commands ?